# get itemtext from SysListView32

Tags: c#, winapi, listview, sendmessage

i am trying to get the text in SysListView32 from another app by C#.
i can get the `LVM_GETITEMCOUNT` well but `LVM_GETITEMW = 0x1000 + 13` always returns `-1`. how can i get the text by C#? i am new. thanks very much!

```
        ParenthWnd = FindWindow(ParentClass, ParentWindow);
        if (!ParenthWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            zWnd = FindWindowEx(ParenthWnd, zWnd, zClass, zWindow);
            if (!zWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                int user = SendMessage(zWnd, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to work harder to read and write the `LVITEM` memory since you are working with a control owned by another process. You therefore need to read and write memory in that process. You can't do that without calling `ReadProcessMemory`, `WriteProcessMemory` etc.

The most commonly cited example of the techniques involved is this Code Project article: [Stealing Program's Memory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/int64_memsteal.aspx?msg=1646056).  Watch out for 32/64 bit gotchas.

Comment: i got it !thank u very much.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/2212/thread/8529ff18-8b63-46c1-bb28-b469e298ee0c/